# How to cast pointer value to enumeration?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following:

```
enum TestEnum { One=1, Two, Three };

int main()
{
    char const* data = reinterpret_cast<char const*>(One);

    TestEnum e = reinterpret_cast<TestEnum>(data);
}
```

Clang fails to compile this:

```
main.cpp:11:18: error: reinterpret_cast from 'const char *' to 'TestEnum' is not allowed
    TestEnum e = reinterpret_cast<TestEnum>(data);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Why won't `reinterpret_cast` work in this situation? I've tried removing `const` but that doesn't make a difference. I didn't see anything in the C++11 specification that states special behavior for enumerations.

Comment: `TestEnum e = *reinterpret_cast<TestEnum const *>(data);` But what on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: @Praetorian Won't that be undefined behavior? `data` doesn't truly hold a pointer, the value should be `0x00000001` right? You're dereferencing it after the cast, isn't that the same as trying to access the memory at address 0x1?

Comment: @void.pointer Although I won't find the relevant text myself, 5.2.10/1 states that any conversions not explicitly listed cannot be performed.

Comment: `TestEnum e = reinterpret_cast<const TestEnum&>(data);`

Comment: Maybe, I was only trying to get it to compile :)

Comment: @remyabel Hit the nail on the head. I keep forgetting that exact wording and I expect each scenario to be explicitly covered. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From 5.2.10/4: "A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it." Enums are not integral types.

(The reverse direction is allowed by paragraph 5: "A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a pointer.")